# Correct way of using fsolve in R (pracma package)

Tags: r

I am trying to execute the following code to solve a system of nonlinear equations using R:

```
library(pracma)
t <- read.csv("values-try.csv", header=F, sep=",")
x0 <- as.matrix( c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
Gr <- 9.807
F <- function (x) {
    x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3]; x4 <- x[4]; x5 <- x[5]; x6 <- x[6]
as.matrix( c( (t[1,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[1,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[1,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2, 
              (t[2,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[2,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[2,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2, 
              (t[3,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[3,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[3,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2,
              (t[4,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[4,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[4,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2, 
              (t[5,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[5,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[5,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2, 
              (t[6,1] - x1)^2/x2^2 + (t[6,2] - x3)^2/x4^2 + (t[6,3] - x5)^2/x6^2 - Gr^2), ncol = 1)
}
fsolve(F, x0)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in if (norm(s, "F") < tol || norm(as.matrix(ynew), "F") < tol) break :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: fsolve -> broyden
Execution halted
```

Any hints or resolving the error?

The values-try.csv looks like this:

```
0.1191419256974832, -0.2806359683994824, -9.755712465258934
0.3194200198415491, 0.05681698915395282, -9.711375649078391
0.05320046522270569, 0.21071993729858585, -9.711942750423542
0.056291795600583824, 0.20746318577998762, -9.697096562782926
-0.18870002789891743, -0.03873042128470452, -9.70831243701548
0.13239301222057243, -9.790554976542873, -0.9744148062871234
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the common zeroes of a set of polynomials is always tricky business. I somehow doubt the polynomials in your example do have such an exact common zero. Anyway, implementations like the one in fsolve will have problems with too small gradients or step lengths.

A better idea might be to apply a least-squares solver, i.e., minimize the sum of squares of the components of F. Function pracma::lsqnonlin will do this, squaring and summing the components of F automatically.

```
library(pracma)
x0 <- as.matrix( c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
sol = lsqnonlin(F, x0, options=list(tolx=1e-12, tolg=1e-12))
sol$x
## [1]     0.1061871    32.9875053    -0.5361180
## [4]    59.1224428 68975.6833271  7034.3066917
F(sol$x)
##               [,1]
## [1,]  1.838934e-07
## [2,]  9.420962e-08
## [3,]  2.146091e-05
## [4,] -2.161610e-05
## [5,] -1.225254e-07
## [6,] -3.836504e-10
```

Please note that you will find other minima with different starting points. You didn’t say whether you want to restrict the problem domain; I am quite certain there are no ‘near’ zeros in [-10, 10]^6.